# Replace img tag with the title attribute

Tags: php, regex

I have an HTML string with the following content:

```
<p>your name :
<img title="##name##" src="name.jpg"/></p>
<p>your lastname:
<img title="##lastname##" src="lastname.jpg"/></p>
<p>your email :
<img title="##email##" src="email.jpg"/></p>
<p>submit
<img title="submit" src="submit.jpg"/></p>
```

Now I want to extract all the title attributes (they appear inside a pair of `##` tags), and remove the `<img>` tag and replace it with the extracted title.

The result should look like this:

```
<p>your name :
##name##</p>
<p>your lastname:
##lastname##</p>
<p>your email :
##email##</p>
<p>submit
<img title="submit" src="submit.jpg" title="submit"/></p>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTML parser to achieve this task. Here's a solution using the built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);


$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$length = $tags->length;

for ($i=$length-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
    $tag = $tags->item($i);
    $title = $tag->getAttribute('title');

    // check if title is of the format '##...##'
    if (preg_match('/##\w+?##/', $title)) {
        $textNode = $dom->createTextNode($title);
        $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($textNode, $tag);
    }
}

$html = preg_replace(
    '~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|head|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', 
    $dom->saveHTML()
);
echo $html;
```

Output:

```
<p>your name :
##name##</p>
<p>your lastname:
##lastname##</p>
<p>your email :
##email##</p>
<p>submit
<img title="submit" src="submit.jpg"></p>
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101166)

Comment: thank you, why ##lastname## not replace and don't work!?

Comment: good, but i think in checking format ## this regix is good work. /##([^#]*)##/

Comment: @ArazJafaripur: Why do you think so? That regex matches (and captures) `##` followed by anything that's not a `#` until it finds `##` - In this case, you don't want to capture the title inside the regex - you're already extracting the title attribute with the `getAttribute()` method :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img.*?(##.+##).*?\/>/', '$1', $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can give a try to this :

```
$content = preg_replace('/<img.*?(##.+##).*?\/>/','${1}', $content);
$content = str_replace('##','',$content);
```

Answer (score 0):

So first you want to select any area that: `starts with "<img", then contains "##", then 1 or more characters, then "##", and ends with ">"`

Then in that extracted block you want to find the part that `starts with "##", then 1 or more characters, then ends with "##"`.

By writing it out like this, I hope you can come up with the regex that does this.